PHP response triggers HEX view in Edge debugger
PHP 8.0 on IIS 10.0.
I am calling a php  api through fetch. An exception is triggered due to some issue with an SQL query in the php api, and normally I would get a 500 server error page followed by PHP's error reporting output.
However, now suddenly I get this HEX view which is not exactly helpful, and I am not sure what triggered it. No settings were changed in either php.ini or IIS config.

Any hint?
Thanks

Is there a content type header?

@ChrisHaas no, no content or encoding headers

Without a content-type, the browser uses heuristics to decide how to display the data. For some reason it decided this should be displayed as binary data rather than text.
